# Convert Æ Ø Å into AE OE AA

Tags: php, preg-replace, special-characters, str-replace

Im having problems to convert `æ`, `ø`, and `å` into `ae`, `oe` and `aa`.

I am trying to make a seo friendly url with this function, but it just removes the `æøå` signs.

My function is:

```
function seo_friendly_url($string, $cid) {
    //Unwanted:  {UPPERCASE} ; / ? : @ & = + $ , . ! ~ * ' ( )
    $string = strtolower($string);
    //Convert ÆØÅ
    $string = str_replace(chr(230), 'ae', $string); 
    $string = str_replace(chr(248), 'oe', $string); 
    $string = str_replace(chr(229), 'aa', $string); 
    //Strip any unwanted characters
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);
    //Clean multiple dashes or whitespaces
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
    //Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Does anyone got any ideas on how to solve this issue. I have tried many difference things found around the web, but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the comments on this man page:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Perhaps something like:

```
function seo_friendly_url($url) {
    $url = strtolower($url);
    $url=str_replace('æ','ae',$url);
    $url=str_replace('ø','oe',$url);
    $url=str_replace('å','aa',$url);    
    return urlencode($url);
}
```

would do it?

Comment: I tried this. But it seems that the functions see `$url=str_replace('æ','ae',$url);` as `$url=str_replace('?','ae',$url);` for some reason.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct charset on your document.

Comment: I use Notepad++, and have set it to be `utf-8 (without BOM)`

Comment: Is the document type also UTF8? if you get data in iso-8859-1 and you try to parse it with utf8 characters you will get this type of error